# Firebase Cloud Function + Firebase with update and insert/set

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

when using firebase cloud function, let say if I want to insert some field into the firebase, I use `ref.child().set()`, but when I want to update the child, I can use both `ref.child().update()` and `ref.child().set()`. Is that a correct way to use `ref.child().set()` to update the field if the field is existed and to insert the field if the field is not exist? Because if I use `ref.child().update()`, I need to make sure the field data is inside the firebase. Thank you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no difference in writing the initial value of a node and updating it. Both can be accomplished with either `set()` or `update()`.

The difference between `ref.set(...)` and `ref.update({...})` is that the first replaces everything that currently exists at `ref`, while the second *updates* only the keys/paths that are specified in the parameters.

I highly recommend checking out the [documentation on updating nodes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/save-data#section-update) for an example.